# variable as a selector with $(document).on("change"

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use variable in place of a selector. I need to use $(document).on(); How can I get away with something like this:

```
var checkbox1 = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=checkbox-checked]");
for(var i=0; i<checkbox1.length; i++) {
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   $(document).on("change", checkbox1[i], function() {
      if($(this).is(":checked")) {
         var address = $(this).data("address");
         geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, address);  
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: Don't use a loop to add event handlers. Your code is equivalent to `$(document).on('change', 'input[name="checkbox-checked"]', function () {...`.

Comment: "_I need to use `$(document).on()`_" Why? The elements are already in the DOM.

Comment: Looks like you need to access elements in loop.. try [this](https://api.jquery.com/each/)?

Comment: I'm using paginate and the JavaScript checkbox1[i].addEventListener('change', function(e) { does not work when I  go to next page